# SQL Server 2008 R2 Recursive Update Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a file system app that uses a SQL Server 2008 R2 to keep track of files.  When I remove a file, I want to update parents in the path hierarchy to reflect their new size.  I am using @fid for the current FILE_ID, @size as the FILE_SIZE, and @pid as the FILE_ID of the parent in the hierarchy.

Here is the loop I am using:

```
SELECT @pid=PARENT_ID FROM FILES WHERE FILE_ID=@fid;

WHILE @pid<>0
BEGIN

    UPDATE FILES
    SET 
        FILE_SIZE = 
        -- Avoid potential situation where new file size might incorrectly drop below 0
        CASE 
            WHEN FILE_SIZE-@size>=0 THEN FILE_SIZE-@size
            ELSE 0
        END
    WHERE FILE_ID=@pid;

    SET @fid=@pid;
    SELECT @pid=PARENT_ID FROM FILES WHERE FILE_ID=@fid;
END
```

When I run this, the sizes are not updating.  If I replace the UPDATE with a SELECT, it looks like it should be working correctly.  What is going on?  **Why are the sizes not getting updated?  Is there a better way to do this?**

To add some context, this snip-it is actually running inside another loop so multiple files can be deleted in a batch.  Here is the code in this context:

```
-- Declarations
DECLARE @fid int, @size int, @pid int;
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR 
SELECT 
    FILE_ID, FILE_SIZE 
FROM
    FILES

OPEN c;

-- Initialize variables
FETCH NEXT FROM c 
INTO @fid, @size;

-- Main loop
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    -- Statements to delete the file --

    -- Loop to update sizes --
    SELECT @pid=PARENT_ID FROM FILES WHERE FILE_ID=@fid;
    WHILE @pid<>0
    BEGIN

        UPDATE FILES
        SET 
            FILE_SIZE = 
            CASE 
                WHEN FILE_SIZE-@size>=0 THEN FILE_SIZE-@size
                ELSE 0
            END
        WHERE FILE_ID=@pid;

        SET @fid=@pid;
        SELECT @pid=PARENT_ID FROM FILES WHERE FILE_ID=@fid;
    END

   FETCH NEXT FROM c 
   INTO @fid, @size;
END
CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

Comment: Does the total filesize take a long time to calculate?  What's wrong with deriving it on-the-fly?  Make it be `null`, and have your recursive query fill in with `COALESCE()` as necessary.  Among other things, doing SQL in a loop like that isn't usually recommended.  I guess the other option would be to make a _trigger_ that updates the parents, which should cascade... but this might get interesting once you have two threads (that happen to be reaching the root of the directory)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is definately a better way to do this. The approach you outline is procedural and iterative and great for languages like C# and visual basic, however, for the most efficeint solution in SQL Cursors are the LAST trick you should reach for.

This should work

```
WITH    FileList
AS
(
    -- Select all the files that have no children
    SELECT   f.FILE_ID 
            ,f.FILE_SIZE
            ,f.PARENT_ID
            ,0 AS CHILD_ID
            ,0 AS Depth
    FROM    FILES f
            LEFT JOIN
            FILES f1 ON f.FILE_ID=f1.PARENT_ID
    WHERE   f1.PARENT_ID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    -- Then recursively select thrir parents
    SELECT   f.FILE_ID
            ,fl.FILE_SIZE
            ,f.PARENT_ID
            ,fl.FILE_ID
            ,fl.Depth + 1
    FROM    FileList fl
            INNER JOIN
            FILES f ON f.FILE_ID=fl.PARENT_ID
)
-- With this data update the file size with the sum of all leaf nodes
UPDATE  FILES
SET     FILE_SIZE = (SELECT SUM(FILE_SIZE)
                    FROM    FileList fl
                    WHERE   fl.FILE_ID=FILES.FILE_ID
                    GROUP BY    FILE_ID)
```

One command, no itteration - should be orders of magnitude quicker and you are getting the accurate filesizes propagated all the way up from the leaves each time.

Comment: Thanks!  I think I've been working too hard just to make this work.  I hadn't considered a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post the result, in case it helps.  I hope this is the right way to do it.

I needed to restrict the update to just the affected path, so I ended up using something like this, based on the suggestion from Dale M:

```
-- Since I already have @size and @pid, I use them here
WITH    FileList
AS
(
    -- Select the parent of the delete target
    SELECT   f.FILE_ID 
            ,f.PARENT_ID
            ,f.FILE_SIZE-@size AS FILE_SIZE
    FROM    FILES f 
    WHERE   f.FILE_ID=@pid
    UNION ALL
    -- Then recursively select its parents
    SELECT   f.FILE_ID
            ,f.PARENT_ID
            ,f.FILE_SIZE-@size AS FILE_SIZE
    FROM    FileList fl
            INNER JOIN 
            FILES f ON f.FILE_ID=fl.PARENT_ID
)
-- Update FILES with the size, already adjusted in the CTE above
UPDATE FILES
SET FILE_SIZE=fl.FILE_SIZE
FROM    FILES
        INNER JOIN
        FileList fl ON fl.FILE_ID=FILES.FILE_ID;
```

This is nice because I can start to break this script down into stored procedures.  Thanks again to Dale M!